# Postgres UTC timezone vs local timezone

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I am using PostgreSQL 10. I have a couple of `timestamp with timezone` columns in 3 tables.

Should I use `UTC` as my default timezone in `postgresql.conf` and constantly transforming to `Europe Athens` in every session?

Or have `Europe Athens` as my default, never have to transform, but if other apps access the same database will have to transform  to their timezone?

What is wiser? I guess I have to consider if setting a timezone in the session affects the query speed.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use UTC as my default timezone in postgresql.conf and
> constantly transforming to Europe Athens in every session?

No, this is a waste of effort because the database stores timestamps in UTC anyway, whatever you choose for your default timezone.

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in
> UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean
> Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is
> converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If
> no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be
> in the time zone indicated by the system's [TimeZone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) parameter, and is
> converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: I was thinking that if I set the default to be `europe/athens` and then another app access the DB, it will take 2 transformations to make it eg `europe/zurich` from athens to UTC to zurich. But according to you (and manual) it will be UTC -> athens -> UTC -> zurich. Right? So better to just leave it in UTC and anyone that access it, sets a timezone for the session.